# Counting number of times each value occurs and groupby ID pandas

Tags: excel, pandas

I have an excel file with data like:

| ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | b |

I'm trying for output:

| ID | a_count | b_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

Using pandas dataframes to store the columns and groupby function. But not achieving the desired result. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(df.groupby('ID')['Type'].value_counts()
.unstack()
.rename('{}_count'.format,axis=1)
.reset_index()
.rename_axis(None,axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
(pd
 .crosstab(df['ID'], df['Type'])
 .add_suffix('_count')
 .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
   ID  a_count  b_count
0   1        2        1
1   2        1        1
```